# How to connect to already created ETH wallet using phrase and Web3.py?

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

How to control my already created Ethereum wallet using passphrase and Python with Web3.py?

Comment: SO is a Q&A site about specific programming problems. You haven't posted any code or errors, so it's hard to guess what the problem is, much less how to solve it. The library has [documentation that shows how to use it](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#using-web3). There's an [entire section on keys](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html) Have you tried anything? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the private key from the wallet and import in Web3.py

Some examples

- [Setting up middleware for local transaction signing](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/middleware.html#web3.middleware.construct_sign_and_send_raw_middleware)
- [Working with local private keys](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html?highlight=private%20key)